# Getting/Setting metadata in google cloud storage - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-storage, metadata

I'm trying to set and retrieve metadata from a Google Cloud Storage file, but what I'm trying doesn't seem to work. My code is running in a Kubernetes node/ I have this:

```
// let's make sure that the source file is still there.
let sourceFile = storage.bucket(sourceFileObject.bucket).file( sourceFileObject.name );

const metadata = {
      MD_DL_ERROR: 1
};

console.log( `Setting metadata for ${sourceFileObject.name} to: `, metadata );

sourceFile.setMetadata(metadata, function(err, apiResponse) {

    console.log( `NOW GETTING METADATA for: ${sourceFileObject.name}` );

    sourceFile.getMetadata( function(err, metadata, apiResponse) {
        console.log( "got metadata: ", metadata );
    } );
});
```

But when it runs, what get in the logs doesn't show any indication that the metadata got set at all:

```
 Setting metadata for CA-SACMLS/20022759_000.jpg to:  { MD_DL_ERROR: 1 }

 NOW GETTING METADATA for: CA-SACMLS/20022759_000.jpg
 got metadata:  { kind: 'storage#object',
   id:        'idx-photos-raw-gs.ihouseprd.com/CA-SACMLS/20022759_000.jpg/1588629892121256',
   selfLink:  'https://blah blah blah',
   mediaLink: 'https://blah blah blah',
   name: 'CA-SACMLS/20022759_000.jpg',
   bucket: 'idx-photos-raw-gs.ihouseprd.com',
   generation: '1588629892121256',
   metageneration: '2',
   contentType: 'image/jpg',
   storageClass: 'MULTI_REGIONAL',
   size: '124923',
   md5Hash: 'HASHVAL',
   crc32c: 'koOVMQ==',
   etag: 'CKiFmcObm+kCEAI=',
   timeCreated: '2020-05-04T22:04:52.120Z',
   updated: '2020-05-04T22:04:52.509Z',
   timeStorageClassUpdated: '2020-05-04T22:04:52.120Z' }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this is caused to a delay in the modification of the file's metadata (the 2 request are fired very near and too fast) , I added a sleep function to your code and look like work as is expected.

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const myBucket = storage.bucket('fakebucket');

//sleep definition
const sleep = (waitTimeInMs) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, waitTimeInMs));

const sourceFileObject = myBucket.file('demo.zip');
const metadata = {
    metadata: {
        rrasd: 'custom',
        adsdasdasd: 'go here'
    }
};

sourceFileObject.setMetadata(metadata, function(err, apiResponse) {
    //wait for the propagation
    sleep(250).then(() => {
        sourceFileObject.getMetadata(function(err, metadata, apiResponse) {
            console.log("got metadata: ", metadata);
        })
    })
});
};
```

UPDATE

I changed the code in order to avoid `const metadata` redefinition and looks like work as is expected, the sleep promise is not sharing the metadata variable for that reason my previous code works, thanks @AndyWallace for this tip

```
  const nmetadata = {
  metadata: {
    rr123809123asd: 'custom'
  }
};
  sourceFileObject.setMetadata(nmetadata, function(err, apiResponse) {
    sourceFileObject.getMetadata( function(err, metadata, apiResponse) {
      console.log( "got metadata: ", metadata );
    })
   });
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have handled it. For others reading the solution, note the redefinition of the const metadata - that is also key. Annoying, but key.

Comment: @Andy Wallace So are you saying that "metadata" is, like, a reserved word and that you shouldn't use it casually as a property name? Seems reasonable. I gave myself a heap of trouble recently when I gave an object a property I called "type",